# Getting two pieces of state in a single component: one from a API request, another from a form value

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I try to wireup two pieces of state into a single component (List.js): one from a API JSON request, the other from a form value placed in Form.js.

Only I need to pull the form data into List.js and I don't need to send it to any server

```
// Form.js  FILE
class Form extends React.Component {
       onSubmit(formValue){
         // I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO PUT HERE, AS ONLY I NEED TO PASS 
         // THIS FORM VALUE TO THE List.js COMPONENT
          }
        render(){
           return (
            <form 
                onSubmit{this.props.handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} >
               <Field name="search" component="input" 
                       placeholder="Search" />
               <button>Search</button>
             </form>
              )
          }

  }
export default reduxForm({
           form : 'search'
         })(Form);

// List.js FILE
class List extends React.Component {
            .......
            render() {
              console.log(this.props.term) //FORM VALUE FROM Form.js
               }

     }
const mapStateToProps=(state)=>{
       return {
          data: state.dataFromAPI,
          term: state.form // form IS THE KEY FROM REDUCER OF 
                           // REDUX-FORM
        }
    }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps,{
        fetchData // ACTION TO FETCH DATA FROM API
       })(List);
```

I expect to display in a single component List.js those two pieces of data: one through a call to a action creator in the same component List.js (this part is sorted), the other from a form value in Form.js

Answer (score 0):

I have taken off all the redux-form dependency.
I think for what I wanted, one single input box,  it was no needed and complicated the code. So, I used the normal form, create a state in the Form file and from here I wired to a action creator in actions and update this piece of state in the reducer. So, I can access the two pieces of state from any component.